# Lua inserting a record to a table is failing

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a main script as follows . This script is called script.lua (for the sake of this example)

```
require "modules\\myparentclass"
require "modules\\condition"
require "modules\\helpers"
require "constants"

parentclass = MyParentClass:new()
print ("MyParentClass Type : " .. parentclass:getCode())

-- add conditions

-- condition 1
condition1 = Condition:new(nil,"Are you happy?" , "YES")
parentclass:addCondition(condition1)

-- -- condition 2
condition2 = Condition:new(nil,"Are you sad?" , "NO")
parentclass:addCondition(condition2)


local l = parentclass:getConditions()

print(l[2]:getQuestion())
```

I have another class called MyParentClass whose code is as follows

```
require "constants"
require "modules\\condition"
require "modules\\helpers"

-- Meta class
MyParentClass = {code = ""}


function MyParentClass:new (o)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.condition = condition
   self.conditions = {}
   return o
end

function MyParentClass:getCode ()
   return "Parent Class"
end

function MyParentClass:addCondition(condition)
    print(condition)
    table.insert(self.conditions,condition)
    print('record inserted')
    -- self.conditions = {next= self.conditions, value = condition}
end

function MyParentClass:getConditions()
    return self.conditions
end
```

and I have a third class , Conditions which is as follows

```
require "constants"


-- Meta class
Condition = {question="", answer=""}

function Condition:new (o, question,answer)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.question = question or nil 
   self.answer = answer or nil
   return o
end


function Condition:getCode ()
   return CONDITION_TYPE
end

function Condition:getQuestion()
    return self.question
end

function Condition:getAnswer() 
    return self.answer
end
```

The idea is that in the main script (script.lua) ,

1. I can create a new parent class.
2. Each parent class can have multiple conditions (aka questions).

For me, the first part is working. However I am failing with the second part. Whenever I run the script , I get two instances of the second question. Please see the below snapshot for more details.

[image].

Ideally, I would like to have both the conditions displayed (`"are you happy?"` and `"are you sad?"`) but that is currently not the case.

Can you please help me out with this one?

Comment: You should probably use `local o = o or {}`.

Comment: function arguments are local by nature.
o = o or {}
is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your constructor

```
function Condition:new (o, question,answer)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.question = question or nil 
   self.answer = answer or nil
   return o
end
```

Everytime you call this you change the value of Condition.question and Condition.answer as self refers to Condition, not to your new object o!

So what you actually do is create 2 new tables condition1 and condition2 which both don't have their own .answer and .question. Therefor you access their metatable Condition which after you created condition2 contains: "Are you sad?" , "NO")

If you want to initialize members in your constructor you have to use o.answer and o.question.

Make sure you understand how that metatable stuff actually works.

Comment: thanks Piglet.. that worked.. and yes I should get to know more about metatables. thanks once again.